# Why was Sodom & Gomorrah considered to have sinned ( Khet) instead of (Avon or Pasha)?

Tags: words

From Parashah Lech Lekha we see that Sodom people were mentioned as **wicked** and **sinners** against the Lord Gen 13-[13] & In parashat Vayera we are again told they were **sinners**. Gen 18 [20] If **`sin (Khet)`** is categorized as unintentional wrong doing. Can we say that the people were unaware since the two words(AVON &/or PASHA)are not used in the text? Or can we say that their guilt is contained in the word **(Ra/wicked)**?

Answer (score 2):

[Rav Hirsch](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/showrashi/true#v20) explains that חטאתם is not necessarily *inadvertant sinning* but is used here in the sense of *moral degeneracy, their forsaking דרך ה*. That is they could have called it *inadvertant* because

> Concerning sexual excesses there is generally no no just outcry, it is
> thought to be no matter for the civil authorities, they can simply due
> to the prevailing laxity of morals, at moat, a sin against Hashem,
> they can even become the mode and fashion, are in any case excusable,
> over that there is no great outcry.

Thus because the people of Sodom were *following the law*, that is completely obeying the legal system that they had instituted, the regarded **themselves** as completely justified. Indeed Rav Hirsch in [Vaera 19:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214/jewish/Chapter-19.htm/showrashi/true#v4) points out that every group within society, even those that would ordinarily be at loggerheads, joined in the attack on Lot and his family.